# Why does is.recursive return TRUE for a function

Tags: r

According to the help, `is.recursive(x)` "returns TRUE if x has a recursive (list-like) structure and FALSE otherwise".  I am confused why it returns TRUE when x is a function.  For example:

```
is.recursive(mean)
# [1] TRUE
```

But it does not seem that functions can be recursive in any meaningful sense, particularly since they are not even sub-settable:

```
mean[[1]]
# Error in mean[[1]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Is this an oversight in the R source code, or is there a valid reason that functions should be considered recursive?

Comment: I think, and am still learning!, The error occurs because you try to subset  a variable which represents a function (here `mean`) and you use `[` to subset it like you would do it in dataframes or vectors.... I further think that your intention is not to subset but to access an item within a function with `$`. This may make not much sense in normal R, but it is possible: See here <https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2019/02/12/object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function actually is a recursive structure, I think just for safety reasons they decided not to provide a default method for the `[[` function. You can get the more list-like representation with `as.list()`

```
str(as.list(mean))
# $ x  : symbol 
# $ ...: symbol 
# $    : language UseMethod("mean")
```

So what you get is a list for your parameters and then the function body. If you want to get the body directly you can do

```
body(mean)
body(mean)[[1]]
```

and that does return the body as an expression that you can subset.

So functions are basically stored as lists of lists, therefore they are recursive.

Answer (score 0):

From the help file `?is.recursive`:

> Most types of objects are regarded as recursive. Exceptions are the atomic types, NULL, symbols (as given by as.name), S4 objects with slots, external pointers, and—rarely visible from R—weak references and byte code, see typeof.

Since a function isn't one of these types of objects it is not regarded as atomic and is regarded as recursive.

The other way to look at this is that atomic objects can only be a single type of data (an integer, a character, an s4 definition of data, a pointer, etc.). A recursive object is an object that can have multiple types of data in it such as a list. A function can have multiple types of data in it (and philosophically, is a procedure and not a set of atomic data).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but I don't think this really answers the question.  I already know that functions are not on the list of exceptions to `is.recursive` - that was my jumping off point for the question, because it seems that they *should* be.    Your statement that "A function can have multiple types of data in it" is not correct afaik - a function contains only parsable language and nothing else.  This is quite distinct from the objects returned by a function call, which can of course be recursive.

Comment: @dww:  No, functions can contain lots of things besides parsable language.  MrFlick's answer shows some examples.  Another example is a number or character constant:  when part of a function, they are no different than when they are in vectors, e.g. `body(mean)[[2]]` is a character vector.

Comment: MrFlick's answer is much better than mine.

Comment: Another point on this is that a function can return different results depending on the inputs. A single function can return a number sometimes but a character other times. If you only look at mean you could say that one instance of a function has a single structure and output, but if you only look at a single list you could also say that single list only has one possible structure. There are cases where the output of a function is not atomic.